# hibernate MappingException column should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

Имеется сущность

```
public class RealEstateType {
private long customer_id;
private String name;
private Customer customerByCustomerId;

@Id
@Column(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public long getCustomerId() {
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomerId(long id) {
    this.customer_id = id;
}
```

которая описывает таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE db.real_estate_type (
  customer_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES db.customer (id)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

У которой `customer_id` является `FOREIGN KEY`

Hibernate кидает исключение при `@Column(name = "customer_id")` , `@Column(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)`, `@Column(name = "customer_id", insertable = true, updatable = false)`

```
amework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: hibernate.model.df.RealEstateType column: customer_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

Но если удалить `customer_id` и PK сделать  `@Id @Column(name = "name")`, то все работает.

Если оставить `customer_id` и PK сделать  `@Id @Column(name = "name")`, то получаем такую же ошибку.

Объясните мне причину такого поведения и как его решить?

Comment: У вас как-то странно, customer_id - FK, но вы его объявляете как PK.

Comment: БЕЗ PK не позволяет Hibernate описывать сущность

Comment: Значит надо его создать отдельный полем. Хибернейт не может без ПК, но он должен быть ПК.

Comment: нет. можно @Embeddable юзать. но это совсем другая история

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае аннотация `@Id` не причем, по тексту исключения похоже, что второе поле в сущности ссылается на ту же самую колонку "customer_id". 
Покажите класс сущности из вопроса полностью, там случайно на getter-е для `private Customer customerByCustomerId;` нет аннотаций со ссылкой на ту же колонку (например `@OneToOne`)? Если есть, то одно из двух полей должно быть помечено как `insert="false", update="false"`

Comment: да. ты прав. тогда непонятно почему хибернейт так сгенерировал мне сущность...

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. Случайно в скопировал @Column с одинаковыми значениями value

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).